# Is the hadees in regards city population exceeding its limit authenticate?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I am a Civil Engineering student and I read somewhere in my Urban Planning course that there is a hadees that *"When the population of a city exceeds beyond a limit,then new city should be created, otherwise many socio-economical problems might develop"*

Is it really a hadees? Can you please verify this hadees and give its reference?

Comment: Ok i Think its not a hadees. These the wise words of Allama Iqbal http://khudi.pk/iqbals-encounter-with-mussolini/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the authenticity of this hadees or the source of this hadees. However, Allama Iqbal during his Europe studies trip, when he met the Italian dictator Mussolini, Allama narrated this hadees and Mussolini struck the table with hand (Sorry I don't know the English equivalent of "mukka") and said " This is the exact solution."

http://khudi.pk/iqbals-encounter-with-mussolini/

Comment: http://khudi.pk/iqbals-encounter-with-mussolini/

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,

I don't remember the full Hades but "a new big cities will be build is in it", as for the "socio-economical problems" i did not read it anywhere.
To be noted that this Hades is for end of times.